# How to handle scrollbar wrapping?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a `.sidebar` and a `.content` div, wrapped in a flexbox. I want to make the content scrollable while keeping the sidebar fixed.

**Constraints**

- I cannot use Javascript
- The container max-width must be 600px

**Problem**

If I position it relatively, both sidebar and content scrolls: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mjog1k86/2/)

```
.flex{
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.flex > *{
    border: 1px solid green;
}

.sidebar{
  width: 200px;
}

.content{
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.content p{
  font-size: 48px;
}
```

If I position it absolutely, the scrollbar leaves its beautiful right corner to wrap around 600px container: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mjog1k86/3/)

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex-wrapper{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
}

.flex{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 100%;
}

.flex > *{
    border: 1px solid green;
}

.sidebar{
  width: 200px;
}

.content{
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.content p{
  font-size: 48px;
}
```

What can I do to make the scrollbar stay at the right edge of the screen instead of wrapping around my fixed width div?

Comment: What workaround do you need? ... Absolute position solves it

Comment: No, I want the scrollbar at the edge of screen, not at the edge of container

Comment: Why the max-width of 600px? ... Since you use `flex: 1` on content, it will always be 600px, or you want it in another way?

Comment: i want the addition of sidebar and content to be max 600px

Comment: I can't see the need of flexbox though... https://jsfiddle.net/mjog1k86/4/

Comment: Wow... thanks. That did the trick :D

Comment: Posted a solution for you...even more slimmed down to keep the markup/CSS simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use Flexbox for that, just remove the wrappers and give the sidebar a fixed position.

In addition I used a media query to control the left edge of the two.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.sidebar, .content {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: calc(50% - 300px);
  width: 200px;
}
.content {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin-left: calc(50% - 100px);
}
.content p {
  font-size: 48px;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .sidebar {
    left: 0;
  }
  .content {
    margin-left: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
  <div class="sidebar">
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Contacts</li>
      <li>Monkeys</li>
      <lI>Pigeons</lI>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
      <p>
        We have got the best monkeys in entire europe.
      </p>
      <p>
        We have also got some really good pigeons.
      </p>
      <p>
        One pigeon scored more than 1500 in 2016 SAT exams.
      </p>
      <p>
        The monkey was quite jealous of him to be honest.
      </p>
      <p>
        But they are still besties so far... and will be forever
      </p>
  </div>
```